# Como iniciar um download automaticamente quando o usuário entra em uma página especifica

Tags: c#, mvc, download

Eu tenho uma aplicação MVC C#, onde após o login (será na primeira vez que acessa a plataforma) o sistema inicie o download de alguns arquivos (os arquivos mudam de acordo com a necessidade do departamento, do mesmo modo que pode aumentar o número de arquivos ou diminuir).

Eu já tinha um código que gerava o download dinâmico, porém, não sei como fazer ele ser automático.

```
public ActionResult Download(string nome, string cpf)
    {
        try
        {
            string contentType = "";
            var arquivos = ListaArquivos();
            string nomeArquivo = (from arquivo in arquivos
                                  where arquivo.Nome == nome
                                  select arquivo.Caminho).First();
            string extensao = Path.GetExtension(nomeArquivo);
            string nomeArquivoV = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nomeArquivo);
            if (extensao.Equals(".pdf"))
                contentType = "application/pdf";
            if (extensao.Equals(".jpg") || extensao.Equals(".gif") || extensao.Equals(".png")) contentType = "application/image";
            if (extensao.Equals(".txt")) contentType = "text/plain";
            if (extensao.Equals(".docx")) contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            if (extensao.Equals(".doc")) contentType = "application/msword";
            File(nomeArquivo, contentType, nomeArquivoV + extensao);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = true;
            TempData["Message"] = $"Não é possível realizar o download do Anexo! - {ex.ToString()}";
            return RedirectToAction("Formulario", new { cpf = cpf });
        }
    }

    private List<UploadFileResultVM> ListaArquivos()
    {
        List<UploadFileResultVM> lstArquivos = new List<UploadFileResultVM>();
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(_localUpload));

        foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            lstArquivos.Add(new UploadFileResultVM()
            {
                Nome = item.Name,
                Caminho = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name
            });
        }
        return lstArquivos;
    }
```

E novamente, estou fazendo dessa forma pois não existe um padrão para os arquivos a serem baixados, a quantidade varia, cada área tem um padrão.
A diferenciação das áreas já sei como resolver, o problema é o inicio automático do download quando o usuário acessar a página.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa retornar o arquivo:

```
return File(nomeArquivo, contentType, nomeArquivoV + extensao);
```